# Select p inside 2 divs with jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Im tweaking my jquery implementation in my HTML and the way my site is structured, I can't really get the `$` to call the m1 paragraph. I've tried with `$('p[.m1]')` and it doesn't work. I also tried putting `$('#top #one .classone p.m1')` and still no results. Anyone knows the solution?

```
<div id="top">
<div id="one">
    <div class="classone">
        <p class="m1"></p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

$('p[.m1]').html(scn[0]);
```

Comment: What does `scn[0]` contain? Have you considered that perhaps your issue is that whatever you're trying to insert into the .m1 p tag is invalid?

Comment: Were our answers helpful?

Answer (score 1):

**[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/b4Ajy/1/)**

```
$('#one > div.classone').find('p.m1').html(scn[0]);
```

Not sure of your site structure and how many selectors you need. My code checks for `p` with class `.m1` inside a `div` with class `classone` inside `#one`.

Answer (score 0):

Use that:

```
$('#one').find('p.m1').html(scn[0]);
```

Comment: The only problem with this is that it forces a DOM search, which is slower than direct access, I would think. If you have to go this route, I think the faster method would be: `$("#one .m1")` wouldn't it?

Comment: No, it wouldn't, find() is faster. Of course a direct access would be fatser but i suppose OP want to filter in some way, getting only .m1 elements inside div with id #one

Comment: (Genuinely curious, not being argumentative), why is find() faster? Doesn't `$("#one .m1")` evaluate to native `document.querySelector()` in most browsers that support it?

Answer (score 0):

Uh, nope.

Try this:

```
$("p.m1").html();
```

or

```
$(".m1").html();
```

`[]` is for attribute selectors.

Answer (score 0):

this should work fine

```
$("p.m1").html();
```